# Crawling extratorrent.cc using Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl www.extratorrent.cc using Scrapy. Below is my spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from extra.items import *

class extraSpider(CrawlSpider):

name = 'extraSpider'
allowed_domains = ['extratorrent.cc']
start_urls = ['http://www.extratorrent.cc/torrent']
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/\d+/\S+']), 'parse_torrent')]

def parse_torrent(self, response):
    torrent = TorrentItem()
    torrent['url'] = response.url
    torrent['name'] = response.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/h1").extract()
    torrent['description'] = response.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[4]").extract()
    torrent['size'] = response.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]").extract()        
    return torrent
```

In the generated JSON file, I just get the url variable but not the others, viz. description, size and name.

I do not know where am I going wrong, tried experimenting by changing Xpaths, but all in vain. There is something very small thing that I'm missing out.

Comment: change the start-url, 

it gives **Torrent not found in our database.** response

Comment: Changed it. Still the same problem.

Comment: could you get me the link here ? I mean start_url

Comment: start_urls = ['http://www.extratorrent.cc/today]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in the code, this might help

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from extra.items import *


class extraSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'extraSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['extratorrent.cc']
    start_urls = ['http://www.extratorrent.cc/torrent']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/\d+/\S+']), 'parse_torrent')]

    def parse_torrent(self, response):
        url = response.url
        name = response.xpath(
            "//h1/b/text()").extract()
        name = name[0].strip() if name else 'N/A'
        description = response.xpath(
            '//div[@class="borderdark"]//text()').extract()
        description = ' '.join(
            ' '.join(description).split()) if description else 'N/A'
        size = response.xpath(
            '//td[@class="tabledata1" and contains(text(), "Total Size:")]/following-sibling::td[@class="tabledata0" and position()=1]/text()').extract()
        size = size[0].strip().replace(u'\xa0', ' ') if size else 'N/A'
        torrent = TorrentItem(
            url=url,
            name=name,
            description=description,
            size=size)
        yield torrent
```

I'm appending some sample output here,

```
{'description': u'1 CD DVDRip - x264 AAC Stereo Audio English & Arabic Subtitles Specs: Format : Matroska File size : 701 MiB Duration : 2h 9mn Overall bit rate : 756 Kbps Encoded date : UTC 2015-04-14 21:26:04 Video Format : AVC Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec Format profile : [email protected] /* <![CDATA[ */!function(){try{var t="currentScript"in document?document.currentScript:function(){for(var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute("cf-hash"))return t[e]}();if(t&&t.previousSibling){var e,r,n,i,c=t.previousSibling,a=c.getAttribute("data-cfemail");if(a){for(e="",r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16),n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)i=parseInt(a.substr(n,2),16)^r,e+=String.fromCharCode(i);e=document.createTextNode(e),c.parentNode.replaceChild(e,c)}}}catch(u){}}();/* ]]> */ Nominal bit rate : 687 Kbps Width : 640 pixels Height : 272 pixels Display aspect ratio : 2.35:1 Frame rate mode : Constant Frame rate : 23.976 fps Bit depth : 8 bits Scan type : Progressive Audio Format : AAC Format profile : LC Channel(s) : 2 channels Channel positions : Front: L R Sampling rate : 48.0 KHz Language : Hindi Subtitle Language : English & Arabic Chapters : YES SAMPLE Included A DDR Exclusive Release 1 posted by mard22 (2015-04-14 23:37:41) thankssssss 2 posted by harpreets088 (2015-04-15 04:09:57) Thanks 3 posted by j0k3r777 (2015-04-15 05:23:49) thank you dude 4 posted by DEVENDRA_SINGH140992 (2015-04-15 06:25:21) PLS UPLOAD Badlapur 2015 720p BRRIP magic mike xxl music community Flying Swords of Dragon Gate X-Art - Daphne, Katia ado.net sex Taylor Swift - I Knew You Were Trouble arremessa teu bumbum na vara dvd dava foxx interstellar urbin4hd ETTV adult ja rule mary j blige iyisin tabi the blacllist porn peter+andre+big+night Shyla.Stylez, Gianna Michaels you mad or nah x men first class 2011 zuma \u03bf\u03c4\u03b1\u03bd \u03b1\u03b3\u03b3\u03b5\u03bb\u03b7 \u03ba\u03bb\u03b5\u03bd\u03b5 \u03c0\u03b1\u03c0\u03b1\u03c1\u03b9\u03b6\u03bf\u03c5 mistresst truffle butter Nicki Minaj Joanna Angel, Small Hands, Scarlet LaVey ETRG 7 data recovery Hawaii.Five-0 doom 2005 xvid Rang Rasiya picasa39 el-nino-2014 vikings S02E06 souchon voulzy derriere les mots anime straponcum mukti bengali movie movie might med s02e13 The Night That Panic America riley jenner the flash scarface ft lil wayne & bun b forgot about me down teugu 50 cent \u0627\u0646\u0633 \u0643\u0631\u064a\u0645 \u0643\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0645\u0631 \u0639\u062d\u0633\u0627\u0628\u0643 \u062a\u062d\u0645\u064a\u0644 YIFY big sean idfwu farrah flower software son of satiyamurti telugu full movie DDR jovanotti si alza il vento omar ruiz el americano 2015 hindi movies video mummyefaa blacked Jillian Janson Yellow Claw/Ayden - Till It Hurts Resident evil animated Monitoring',
     'name': u'Badlapur *2015* 1CD - x264 - DvDrip - AAC - MSubs [DDR] torrent',
     'size': u'708.25 MB',
     'url': 'http://extratorrent.cc/torrent/4140564/Badlapur+*2015*+1CD+-+x264+-+DvDrip+-+AAC+-+MSubs+%5BDDR%5D.html'}
```

Comment: Thanks. But from where did you generate the Xpath. I normally browse the site and get Xpath using Google developer tools.

Comment: please don't directly copy from browser, you have to make some adjustments and make it compact. You can get the xpath tutorial from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

Comment: Okay @Jithin. I'll chk it.

Comment: You must have used Selenium. I have heard quite good things about it. Do you recommend using it over Scrapy ?

Comment: @Vivek please don't use selenium unless you don't have any other option left with you. Its much slower compared to scrapy and cost is somewhat high too because you have to open a **browser** for requests and all. At worst case if scrapy not working for your problem you can go for that. At certain stage scrapy fails, especially with Javascript there you can go with Selenium.

Comment: Jithin, I tried to crawl a page with extension ".do" using cURL, but it doesn't seem possible. Any idea about .do pages ?